# represent nested for-loops for function with two parameters using same looping variables

Tags: r, apply, mapply

I try to find a more efficient way to write that piece of code,
I considered apply, mapply and sweep, but I see no way how to rewrite it...

points.proj is m x k matrix, data.proj is n x k matrix.

So essentially I'd like to apply fun to each element of points.mat with the corresp. same columnnumber of the other matrix data.mat...the result should be an m x k matrix again.

```
    for(i in 1:m){
      for(j in 1:k){
        Bounds[i,j] <- fun(points.proj[i,j],data.proj[,j])
      }}

fun <- function(a,b) sum(a<b)

> points.proj
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    6    5
[2,]    7    6
[3,]    8    5
> data.proj
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    8    3
[2,]    2    0
[3,]    9    4
[4,]    6    7
[5,]    2    9

> Bounds
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    2
[2,]    2    2
[3,]    1    2
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Some information on the function may help. What are its arguments, what in summary does it do?

Comment: In general, if you would like to use points from one matrix and columns from another, you need something like `mapply(f, mat1, rep(split(mat2, col(mat2)), each=nrow(mat1)))`. But if you would like a full explanation and answer, please provide a fully reproducible example with desired output so that your expectations and the solution are the same.

Comment: Sure, its first argument is a scalar, second arg is a vector and it produces a scalar again. Its just a very simple function. I think it should go with some variant of apply possibly nested apply with a function taking two args. Problem is, one apply would not need a margin, but the matrix index

Comment: The advice is the same as for all other users. Before we go down a rabbit hole of solutions and edits. Put up two example matrices and a function similar to yours. Then add the output that should result from the example. That way, there is no confusion as to what you are hoping to get.

Comment: Thank you Pierre, your comment above is a solution, it gives what I need, but it looks actually more complicated, not sure whether that saves time. I will check

Comment: Ok, so it is actually slower! Like double as slow as the double loop.

Comment: I gave you a generalized function. I asked you to provide a real example. I am obviously trying to help you. I will ask you again, please, with sugar on top, provide a real example so that you can receive the proper help.

Comment: Hi Pierre, I edited my post, hope people have an idea now. But its not about the specific function, rather about taking each element of the matrix,  with the corresponding column of the other matrix and put in in fun